# Avoiding circular references with forward declarations, but unable to access class members

Tags: c++, class, pointers, forward-declaration, circular-reference

So, I've got several classes, two of which need to reference each other. I solved circular references with forward declarations in `Entity.h`, just included `Entity.h` in my `Timeline.h` class declaration. Entity has a subclass `Human` which would hopefully call a method in `Timeline` which is `timeline->addEvent(...)`.

Timeline.h

```
#include <queue>
#include "Event.h"

class Timeline {
private:
    std::priority_queue<Event> events;
    long unsigned int currentTime = 0;
public:
    Timeline() = default;
    ~Timeline() = default;

    void addEvent(long unsigned int timestamp, EventType type, Entity *entity);
    void processEvent();
    void getCurrentTime();
};
```

Event.h

```
#include "Entity.h"

class Event {
private:
    long unsigned int timestamp;
    EventType type;
    Entity *entity;
public:
    Event(long unsigned int timestamp, EventType type, Entity *entity);
    ~Event() = default;
    long unsigned int getTimestamp();
    EventType getType();
    Entity *getEntity();

    bool operator<(const Event &rhs) const;
    bool operator>(const Event &rhs) const;
    bool operator<=(const Event &rhs) const;
    bool operator>=(const Event &rhs) const;
};
```

Entity.h

```
class Event;
class Timeline;

class Entity {
protected:
    Timeline *timeline;
    long unsigned int currTimestamp;
public:
    explicit Entity(Timeline *timeline, unsigned int age);
    virtual void processEvent(Event event) = 0;
};
```

Human.cpp (calls timeline->addEvent(...))

```
void Human::sleep(Event event) {
    Animal::sleep(event);
    unsigned int timeBlock = 96;
    this->timeline->addEvent(this->currTimestamp + timeBlock, EventType::AWAKEN, this);
}
```

And error logs

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Timeline’
     this->timeline->addEvent(this->currTimestamp + timeBlock, EventType::AWAKEN, this);

note: forward declaration of ‘class Timeline’
     class Timeline;
```

I guess I'm just confused on why this would be an issue. It was fine using forward declaration when it was just `class Event;` but as soon as `class Timeline;` was added in order to implement `addEvent()` to Entity, it goes full fail. Any suggestions?

Comment: Instead of `long unsigned int` - just say `unsigned long` . Shorter and easier to read.

Comment: Apparently `Human.cpp` does not `#include` what it should (`Timeline.h`), but we lack a [mre] to be sure. Voting to close until we get a more complete (and preferably also more minimal) example.

Comment: #include Timeline.h in Human.cpp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forward declaration only works if you have pointer member, but not actually trying to dereference it.

From a look at your code structure, if Human is subclass of Entity, then in the source code of Human.cpp where you dereference the pointer to Timeline, you need to actually include Timeline.h (instead of fw declaration of it).